# how to set the position for part of the text in UILabel

Tags: swift, text, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

i need to create some NSMutableAttributedString with setting for the text position in UILabel how can i do this in Swift?
The result should be like this
(x+y)³ but instead ³ some text
I write the some code

```
    let stringTest = "(x+y)123"
    let myRange = NSRange(location: 5, length: 3)
    let myAttributeMainText = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)! ]
    let myAttributeDegreeText = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 10.0)! ]
    let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringTest, attributes: myAttributeMainText )
    myString.addAttributes(myAttributeDegreeText, range: myRange)
    testLabel.attributedText = myString
```

please help me find a way to raise the last 3 digits in the top of UILabel

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Character_Attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` for making the numbers appear as exponents, for example:

```
let myAttributeDegreeText = [NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 6, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 10.0)!]
```

[image]